# plt.show() will not work when I attempt plot a degree distribution but it works when I plot a random graph

Tags: python, networkx

I'm new to python so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I am trying to plot a graph with matplot and have been unsuccessful. I'm using network x and when I use plt.show() to show a graph I randomly generated it works fine. But when I attempt to use it to plot a degree distribution nothing happens.

I suspect I am not correctly adding a subplot but I am really clueless after that.

Here is my code so far:

```
import networkx as nx

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p=1.0/6.0

g=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10,p)
nx.draw(g)

plt.show()

def deg_dist()

    deg = {}

    for n in g.nodes():

       d = g.degree(n)

       if d not in deg:

           deg[d] = 0

       deg[d] += 1

    items = sorted(deg.items())

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.plot([k for (k,v) in items], [v for (k,v) in items ])

    plt.title('Degree Distribution')

    fig.show()
```

Comment: Take a look at the example here for hints:http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/degree_histogram.html

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm wrong but... Did you at least call this `deg_dist` function ? If not, well nothing will happen here.

Comment: When I copy pasted my code I think I deleted while editing out the extraneous stuff.